# communication between two applications on two systems

Tags: java, web-services

Suppose there are two Systems A and B and applicationA and applicationB are running on them respectively.
What are the way they can call each other's method and can even transfer files.
I could think of web services and making client-server relation or serializat-deserialization and then make it working.
Any other suggestions are the above one correct.

Comment: er client - server ?

Comment: You can refer some technique such as JMS, JMX or make your own socket handler for this requirement.

Comment: You may also consider [RMI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/) , this is an old way, but may faster to implement

Comment: Thanks a lot

Antony and Anton